# Prevent canvas element from manipulating others depending on order

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been experimenting with canvas and things were going pretty well. However when it came time to rotate an object I had the hardest time getting it to rotate. When I finally did I found that depending on the order the objects being initiated it. The object with the rotation attributes would get passed on to objects being called after it.

All my objects were put into their own functions, and then called by a draw function. I am curious if this is always true and I have to be conscious of my objects order of initiation or if there is something I am missing.

Below if you move Obj1 and Obj2 before or after each other you will see the results are different. My goal is to have Obj1 before Obj2 and only have Obj1 rotated.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  x = 470,
  y = 260;

 canvas.width = 500;
 canvas.height = 500;

 function Obj1(){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.translate(100,0);
 ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y + 10, 20, 45);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
 ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
 }

 function Obj2(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0,300,100, 200);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
 

 function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  Obj1();
  Obj2();
 }
 draw();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please include some code showing your problem. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Context2d transform operations are applied to the whole context, as soon as it is set. If you don't need it anymore, call `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` to reset the transformation matrix.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: A lot of confusions in here : `fillRect` is a shorthand for `beginPath(); rect()` and `fill()`. You have to set your `fillStyle` before calling it and you don't even need `beginPath()`if you're only using this method. `closePath`will not do what you think it will, it is not related to `beginPath()`, it will just draw a line from the last set point of your path to the first one. And as said in previous comment, and in answer below, transform operations are global to the whole context. You have to reset it to its initial state after your drawings.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for information, I managed to solve it with MDN reference below. But hat tip to you for the explanation for the above comment. That as actually really helpful because I didn't realize there was a short hand or the meaing of the other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the rotation matrix after rotating the object

Whats happening is that the transforms are cascading .
Rendering happens as a stack not a per element basis .

The order of operations is

```
TRANSFORM 
  DRAW
RESET
DRAW
```

This is also a recursive process .
You can say rotate the world scene / view port and also individual object .

```
TRANSFORM
  TRANSFORM 
    DRAW
  RESET
  TRANSFORM
    DRAW
  RESET
RESET
```

If you post a simple code example I can review it for you

Have a look at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations

```
function Obj1(){
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(100,0);
ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(x, y + 10, 20, 45);
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.restore();
}
```

I believe off the top of my head .

Comment: And the easy way to reset the transform matrix is to call `ctx.setTransform (1,0,0,1,0,0)`.